# The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.3) is ignored

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, gradle

what can i do in this situation? In Android Studio 4, I'm seeing this issue: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (28.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (29.0.2) for Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0. Android SDK Build Tools 26.0.2 will be used.

Comment: Basically, just have to change buildToolsVersion to the one which was stated in the log.

Answer (score 12):

Change your buildToolsVersion to '29.0.2' in build.gradle file.

Answer (score 1):

As on version Android 4.1.2 it says remove buildToolsVersion "28.0.2" from your build.gradle file since it has its own default build tools now and just Sync it. It worked for me.